# Is there a way to add default_scope with update_columns and delete in rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails `5.2.4.1`based application, we want to add `default_scope` to all the queries running in the application. `select` queries are respecting the `default_scope` but the `update_columns`,  `delete` and `update` is not respecting the `default_scope`.

I found a very [old issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7357) related to this in rails `3.2`  but it has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a3c3cfdd0ebba26bb9dfc0bfd4e23a5f336730c0). Now in Rails `5.2` I am not able to find any possible way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scopes are for collections. All the methods mentioned `update_columns`, `delete` and `update` are called upon a single record, not upon a collection. What is the expected behaviour when applying  a scope on a single record aka an instance?

Comment: `Model.find(id)` apply the default scope.

Comment: Yes, that is called upon a collection. Say you have `instance = Model.unscoped.find(id)` how do you expect to apply the default scope when running `instance.update_columns(attribute: 'value')`? What is the expected result when `instance` conforms to the default scope and what do you expect when `instance` does not conform to the default scope?

Comment: I got your point. But actually we have `default_scope` as the current company_Id and all the query should have the company_id so we can forward specific company_id queries to their respective database. It's like query-based database sharding. So we need the update query to have company_id

Comment: default_scopes are normally a bad idea.  Unless you can find a way to make it project wide with just one call then why not use custom scopes?  You'll run into problems later on bigger projects with default_scopes

Answer (score -1):

#### Rails 6.1 `all_queries: true` option for default scope

[From BigBinary blog](https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-allows-default_scope-to-be-run-on-all-queries):

> Before Rails 6.1 if a `default_scope` was defined in a model it would be applied only for `select` and `insert` queries. Rails 6.1 adds an option `all_queries: true` that could be passed to `default_scope` to make the scope applicable for all queries.

```rb
default_scope -> { where(...) }, all_queries: true
```

> Consider the Article class below.

```rb
class Article
  default_scope -> { where(organization_id: Current.organization_id) }
end

@article.update title: "Hello World"
@article.delete
```

> The `update` and `delete` methods would generate SQL queries as shown below. As we can see that `default_scope` is missing from these queries.

```
UPDATE "articles" SET "title" = $1 WHERE "articles"."id" = $2 [["title", "Hello World"], ["id", 146]]

DELETE FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1  [["id", 146]]
```

> In Rails 6.1 we can solve this problem by passing `all_queries: true` to the `default_scope`.

```rb
class Article
  default_scope -> { where(organization_id: Current.organization_id) }, all_queries: true
end
```

> Then the generated SQL changes to this:

```
UPDATE "articles" SET "title" = $1 WHERE "articles"."id" = $2 AND "articles"."organization_id" = $3  [["title", "Hello World"], ["id", 146], ["organization_id", 314]]

DELETE FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 AND "articles"."organization_id" = $2  [["id", 146], ["organization_id", 314]]
```

Sources:

- [Rails 6.1 allows default_scope to be run on all queries](https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-allows-default_scope-to-be-run-on-all-queries).
- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40720).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The blog post referenced is in error, and jumped the gun on saying the feature was part of Rails 6.1 - it didn't make it into any 6.x release https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb#L88. It's going to be part of Rails 7 by the looks of it, but could obviously be pulled for any reason before then.